# Jboss not recognizing .yml file structure

Tags: java, jboss

I am facing a wierd issue where jboss server is not able to read a .yml file with a nested structure.

I have a simplistic .yml file:

app.yml

```
email.host: somehost
email.port: 10
```

I am loading these properties into a spring boot configuration class and runnig it on jboss as:

EmailConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:/app.yml")
public class EmailConfig {

    @Value("${email.host}")
    private String host;

    @Value("${email.port}")
    private String port;

    // more code...

}
```

This is working fine and the properties are resolved, but when I change the yml file structure to:

app.yml

```
email:
  host: somehost
  port: 10
```

The properties are not resolved, I tried changing the config class to:

EmailConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties("email")
@EnableConfigurationProperties
public class EmailConfig {

    @Getter @Setter
    private String host;

    @Getter @Setter
    private String port;

   // more code...
}
```

But still the properties are not resolved:

Error

```
Could not resolve placeholder 'email.host' in value \"${email.host}\"
```

Do I need any additional configuration for jboss?

Comment: it might be looking for email.host, instead of email: host:

Comment: Following the .yml structure, I have a prefx with `email` and a getter/setter for `host`, so shouldn't that resolve to `email.host` ?

Comment: as you said yourself: email.host works, email: host: doesn't work. so, it would appear it doesn't

Comment: @Stultuske I have another jboss installation on my local machine where this works, on the remote jboss server, it does not.

Comment: so check whether they are the same version or not. whether all of it has the same configuration or not.